# Do I understand negative exponents correctly?

Tags: exponentiation

I know that each time you go up an exponent, you multiply by the base again e.g. $2^2$ to $2^3$. To go down, you you divide by the base. The way I find negative exponents is that I divide 1 by the base^exponent

E.g.

$10^{-3} =$ ?

$10^0 = 1$

$1 ÷ 10 = 0.1$

$0.1 ÷ 10 = 0.01$

$0.01 ÷ 10 = 0.001$

$10^{-3} = 0.001$

The fraction is $\frac{1}{1000}$.

Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes , this is the way it works. In general , we have $a^{-n}=\frac{1}{a^n}$

Comment: OK thank you for helping